# RunKeeper - Health Graph API documentation

Tags: documentation

I am unable to find health graph documentation. This link - https://runkeeper.com/developer/healthgraph, redirects to the home page of RunKeeper. Can someone please provide me the documentation or a legit link for the same?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Runkeeper only allows their current partners to access the Health Graph API. I asked Runkeeper about accessing the API and this is the reply I got:

> Runkeeper:  Thank you for your email -- we're happy to clarify. Our team made the decision to stop accepting new registrations for our Health Graph API, as we want to direct our limited resources towards best serving our current partners. Going forward, we will only be supporting clients we have specifically built a partnership with on our end.
> We’re very sorry for any inconvenience this causes